# QTreeView row removal, causing crash

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I've stumbled upon following problem:
I'm using QTreeView with custom TreeItem implementation. Most of the code is copied from [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html)

Problem is:

When I try to remove row from list program crashes. In most cases it throws an error while accessing parent() in QModelIndex. It seems like it is trying to access non existent object. Below Call stack screen.

Call stack

[image]

I've found a workaround: when i force treeView before deletion of a row to sort it, app doesn't crash. By default column 0 is sorted in descending order, so i must sort it in ascending order and then back in descending order.
I also have custom filter proxy.

TreeItem.cpp:

```
bool TreeItem::removeChildren(int position, int count)
{
    if (position < 0 || position + count >= childItems.size())
        return false;

    for (int row = 0; row < count; ++row)
        delete childItems.takeAt(position);

    return true;
}
```

TreeModel:

```
bool TreeModel::removeRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    TreeItem *parentItem = getItem(parent);
    bool success = true;
    beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1);
    success = parentItem->removeChildren(position, rows);
    endRemoveRows();
    return success;
}
```

Data.cpp:

```
bool Data::removeJob(Job* job)
{
    if (job)
    {
        TreeItem* parent = job->parentItem;
        int jobItemRow = parent->childItems.indexOf(job);
        QModelIndex jobItemIndex = Model->getIndex(jobItemRow, 0, job);
        int dayItemRow = Model->rootItem->childItems.indexOf(parent);

        QModelIndex dayItemtIndex = Model->getIndex(dayItemRow, 0, parent);

        int index = JobList.indexOf(job);

        Model->removeRow(jobItemRow, jobItemIndex.parent());
        JobList.takeAt(index);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

CustomFilter.cpp:

```
bool CustomSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, const QModelIndex &right) const
{
    if (left.data().canConvert<QDateTime>())
    {
        return left.data().toDateTime() < right.data().toDateTime();
    }
    else  if (left.data().canConvert<QString>())
    {
        return left.data().toString() < right.data().toString();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: for me the problem is so vague, that i have no idea which code snippets to copy, once someone who knows anything about this posts, i will add needed code parts.

Comment: Add the part that makes your code reproducible and complete, otherwise it will not work. 
Imagine that for you the problem is vague, which will be for us.

Comment: I have this same issue, but I'm not using a filter/sort proxy. At the moment I'm assuming it has to do with the QTreeView's current selection when the row is removed.